Topology of sets defined by real-valued functions (again)
This is a follow-up to this previous question, but a bit more specific.
Suppose I have a simple Euclidean space $X = \mathbb{R}$, or $X = \mathbb{R}^2$, or $X = \mathbb{R}^3$, and a continuous real-valued function $f:X\to \mathbb R$. I can define sets like:
\begin{align}
A &= \{x \in X: f(x) = 0 \} \\
B &= \{x \in X: f(x) \le 0 \} \\
C &= \{x \in X: f(x) < 0 \} \\
\end{align}
It would be nice if we could say that $A$ is the boundary of $B$, or that $C$ is the interior of $B$. Those statements are not true, in general. If we want them to be true, what extra conditions do we have to impose on $f$.
For example, what if $X = \mathbb{R}$ and $f$ is strictly monotone. Or how about if $f(x) = \|x\| - 1$. Any norm? Or what if $f$ is (strictly?) convex, or Lipschitz, or a polynomial? Or $f(x) = $ signed distance from $x$ to some (convex?) set $S$. I’m open to any suggestions regarding sufficient (or even required) properties of $f$, especially ones that have some geometric flavor.
The answer to my previous question says that $f$ being an open map is sufficient, but that's typically difficult for me to check, so I'm looking for other sufficient conditions.
This paper looks relevant, for the case where $f$ is differentiable, but I haven’t managed to wade through all of it yet.
This answer says that if $f$ is convex, then $\overline{C} = B$.
Context: these sorts of sets are used to model shapes in computer systems, so I’m interested in their topology.

It seems to me that f differentiable everywhere in A with a nonzero differential everywhere in A should do the trick. Of course, this is still quite restrictive and may not be what you are looking for. I should probably also take the time to prove this later.

Thanks. That sounds promising. Intuitively, I’d guess we only need the gradient to be non-zero near the boundary (whatever that means).

@bubba: More concretely, it looks as though you are searching for conditions where the inverse image $f^{-1}(0)$ is a closed manifold.

@naiht: What you are asserting is a sufficient condition to guarantee that $f^{-1}(0)$ will be an $N-1$-dimensional smooth manifold (by the Implicit Function Theorem), if I am not missing anything. The requirement in the question seems to be a bit stronger: that the manifold is closed.

@bubba: I did not mean a closed set (yes, of course $f^{-1}(0)$ is closed if $f$ is continuous). You can check the wikipedia for the definition of a closed manifold (compact with no boundary). Perhaps, you would like conditions whereby $f^{-1}(0)$ is homeomorphic (or diffeomorphic) to the sphere.

@AugustoSantos, $f$ is continuous, so $f^{-1}(0)$ will always be closed? What do you mean by closed? The set $A$ need not be compact in order to be the boundary.

@naiht, I mean 'closed manifold', not closed set (please, refer to my last comment).

Example in $\mathbb{R}^2$: take $f(x,y) = x -y$. Then my topological desires are satisfied, but no compactness or closed manifolds in sight.

I misunderstood the question.

In this case, I believe that the condition given by @nahit answers the question, in view of the Implicit Function Theorem.

It is easy to check that the following conditions are equivalent:

$A$ is the boundary of $B$,

$C$ is the interior of $B$,

the function $f$ attains a local maximum in no points of $A$.


In particular, these conditions are satisfied when one of the following conditions holds:

$X=\mathbb R$ and the function $f$ is strictly monotone,

$f(x)=\|x\|−c$ for each $x\in X$, where $\|\cdot\|$ is any norm on $X$ and $c>0$ is any real number,

the function $f$ is strictly convex (that is, for each distinct $x_1,x_2\in X$, we have $f\left(\frac{x_1+x_2}2\right)<\frac{f(x_1)+f(x_2)}2$).



Seems somewhat related to the comment from @naiht about non-zero gradients

A bit terse, but all very interesting since no differentiability is assumed. Thanks.

@bubba Thanks for your kind words. I was specialized in general topology, not in differential that. If you need more special cases of $f$ to consider, feel free to ask.

I don’t have any other ideas for cases to consider. Inventing cases/conditions is  a large part of my question. I made some guesses regarding conditions that work, but I was hoping that answers would suggest others.
